# Geting route error while creating ecommerce site in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, components, e-commerce

I am trying to create an e-commerce site in Laravel.
getting this error :

Invalid route action: `[HomeComponent]`.

I am getting errors like this :

at `F:\xampp\htdocs\lv8ecom\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteAction.php:92`

```
     88▕      */
     89▕     protected static function makeInvokable($action)
     90▕     {
     91▕         if (! method_exists($action, '__invoke')) {
  ➜  92▕             throw new UnexpectedValueException("Invalid route action: [{$action}]."); 
     93▕         }
     94▕
     95▕         return $action.'@__invoke';
     96▕     }
```

i   `HomeComponent` was not found: Controller class `HomeComponent` for one of your routes was not found. Are you
sure this controller exists and is imported correctly?

```
 1   F:\xampp\htdocs\lv8ecom\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteAction.php:47
      Illuminate\Routing\RouteAction::makeInvokable("HomeComponent")

  2   F:\xampp\htdocs\lv8ecom\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:191
      Illuminate\Routing\RouteAction::parse("/", ["HomeComponent", "HomeComponent"])
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is saying that the route is not found, you can use your routes like this:

```
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index']);
```

`Route::get` = the request method type example `(get / post / put / delete)`

`/home` = the link you would like to access and call the controller at

`App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class` = the controller name, you should create this file and name it as you like

`'index'` = the name of the method inside of the controller